# Is this comparison committing a fallacy?

Tags: fallacies, debate

I am trying to build an argument against a friend:

**Me**: "In your chess games against me, you never resign even when the conclusion is inevitable. I feel that this is a waste of time, and I object."

**Them**: "As a result of never resigning, I occasionally frustrate my opponent so much that they resign the game, so it helps my chess rating to improve. Therefore, it's a good thing to do."

**Me**: "I concede that it improves your rating, but I don't believe that justifies it. For example, *sexually harassing a female opponent may cause her to get upset, play worse, and improve your rating*, but I don't think you would claim that it is therefore acceptable behavior."

**Them**: "Are you seriously equating not resigning in chess with sexual harassment?"

My goal is to show that "a chance to gain rating points" IS NOT the same as "good behavior"

**Is my argument a fallacy? Is his objection correct?**

Comment: as an "immortal god", you are absolutely right! How can (th)he(m) dare to not resign..to argue!???? On the other hand: Why should you (as immortal god) "not(ic)e" it? (either the the "non-resign" either the "harassment"!?)

Comment: The two things are not comparable. Playing chess until you are checkmated is entirely within the rules of the game. It is discourteous to an opponent to play on when you are dead lost, but it is not infringing the rules. An even worse discourtesy in a game with clocks is to walk away and make your opponent wait for your time to run out, but it happens sometimes. Harassing your opponent in any way is against the rules. Even just talking to your opponent is actually against the rules.

Comment: for an "non-immortal god", you are probably wrong and fallacious...and probably "disgusting" ...disregarding "rules" (of "chess", "human social life", "immoral god") ..it seems you (also) only do it for "rating points" (in chess as at [sep]!?;) (improve your end game & be thankful for such a tough opponent!;)

Comment: It's a legitimate comparison if your point is to argue that the goal of winning should be subservient to common courtesy. it is common to illustrate a point by using an example that is more extreme and therefore make the point more pointed. The other person's response is a deflection. Instead of responding to your point, he is deflecting to complaining about your example.

Comment: All analogies limp. The egregiousness does not seem relevant to you because you intend your analogy in a certain way, but that is not the only way others can (and will) see it. You are making a moral argument, but the analogized actions are not morally on a par, as you admit, which both weakens your argument and creates a distraction. This is similar to [Nazi analogies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godwin%27s_law) that tend to derail discussion and are best avoided. As [they quip](https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/Godwins-law), "*whoever mentions Hitler first, loses the argument*".

Comment: It is a fallacious comparison. You are overlooking crucial differences between methods available to your opponent in his quest for an improved rating. In and of itself, playing till checkmate challenges only the adversary's ability to focus for an extended period. The method does not involve anything beyond the chessboard. As such, playing till checkmate falls short of creating the type of external distractions or disturbances that heckling, sexual harassment, and other annoying conduct tend to cause to the adversary.

Comment: In which case you've lost the argument @Conifold 

Comment: Not sure why this was closed. It's a question about the logical structure of an informal argument, which is on-topic for us. I have edited to highlight the underlying question, hopefully that will make it more clear this is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Analogies like the one in question are reasonable from the point of view of logic.

If someone presents an argument to justify something ("This helps my chess rating to improve. Therefore, this is a good thing to do"), it's perfectly logical to point out some objectionable thing the same argument can justify.

The logical response would be: 1) add additional premises to differentiate the cases, 2) reject the original conclusion of the argument, or 3) accept the objectionable conclusion.

Just because they take offence, doesn't mean they're right or they're being logical. And just because they take offence, doesn't mean that isn't an effective way to change their mind. But it also doesn't mean you're right, or being logical, or that it *is* an effective way to change their mind.

---

**However**, analogies are often considered objectionable from a social and emotional point of view.

By making an objectionable analogy, it's often interpreted as you saying the other person would do that thing (despite it being the exact opposite: the analogy makes sense specifically because they find it objectionable). It could also be interpreted as you thinking those things are in the same "category", that you cannot see a differentiating criteria between the two (there might be some validity to this, but you might bring it up if you don't know how *the other person* would differentiate them).

There are also bad-faith or illogical analogies, e.g. you brush your teeth, Hitler brushed his teeth, therefore you're like Hitler - that would be fallacious.

---

I wouldn't say you should or should not make analogies, and I won't write a thesis on how to best change mind. But the above should give some idea of the pros and cons of using analogies.

---

For your analogy, one might suppose they'd differentiate frustrating someone and sexual harassment based on what's legal, within the rules, or socially or morally acceptable - those are often unstated premises/assumptions in arguments (the last 2 especially might complicate matters if you're trying to argue that it shouldn't be socially or morally acceptable). In essence: they consider frustrating others (so much so that they surrender to the frustration and concede) for their own personal benefit to be acceptable behaviour.

So, a reasonable analogy wouldn't focus on other things that can be done for personal benefit, but should rather focus on frustrating others in other circumstances for personal benefit, e.g. cutting in line in front of someone, or begging someone for something nonstop until they give it to you. You're not trying to establish that doing things for personal benefit is bad, but rather that frustrating others is bad.

Although I'd probably just conclude that they're selfish, and remove them from my life, rather than trying to change their mind on that. They might simply accept that frustrating others in other circumstances is fine too. Although then one might be able to have a discussion about the breakdown of courtesy and social order, and how other people won't treat them with kindness if they do such things. But they might also just accept that some people get to be jerks who exploit the good graces of others, and society doesn't break down because most people aren't jerks.

Comment: Thank you! I think a more persuasive person in my position would have found a less confrontational analogy or even avoided analogies altogether. I don't think my analogy is like the "Hitler brushing his teeth" analogy, but I do think it can be easily mistaken for that

Answer (score 1):

Technically a fallacy is a logical error or more precisely a failure in one's reasoning. So it doesn't even mean that what you conclude is wrong, but that the way by which you draw the conclusion is faulty:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy

So in your case you interpret your opponents argument: "As a result of never resigning, I occasionally frustrate my opponent so much that they resign the game, so it helps my chess rating to improve."

To mean "Everything that gives me points is good".

So you try to show the problem with that argument by exaggerating it:

> If everything is good what gives me points

> and sexual harassment gives me points

> then sexual harassment is good

Which would be a valid argument (which just means that if the premises were true, the conclusion MUST follow, that is MUST also be true). Now sexual harassment is obviously not good, so there must be a fallacy within that argument.

That being said though, the fallacy could be as simple as the word everything. If they'd not say "EVERYTHING" is fair game as long as it give me points, but only everything within the rules of chess (...) then you'd be back to square one as they'd still be able to pursue their behavior, but your argument would no longer work as they limited what is allowed under that paradigm, yet they didn't need to give it up entirely. In fact the limitation only relates to a point that they never made to begin with. Which is at best a pyrrhic victory and at worst a rhetoric slight of hand where you pretend (towards an audience) to score points and be ahead of the other person's argument, but where your victories are essentially insignificant to the actual argument.

The other problem is that this is just your interpretation of their position. Their actual claim might be something like: "Lots of people still don't know the basics and try to play beyond their level so despite being a waste of time against a real GM it still works surprisingly often against wannabe GMs, so your argument of it being a waste of time is simply not correct. Case and point it actually earns me points."

Though given that he explicitly refers to them resigning out of frustration over the time wasted that really is just being a dick, though it's within the rules of the game. So this would be more of a question about the essence and purpose of chess, whether it is to win at all costs and with all means available to you or whether it is to win within a given set of written and unwritten rules and whether unwritten rules are an unjust restriction or a necessity of fair game play.

That might sound trivial, but similar to most sports there's actually some debate to be had about what it is even about in the first place. For example people often like to talk about trans women competing in women sports with the context of having an unfair advantage, but at the same time don't bet an eye with regards to the problem that "better genes" (with regards to performing that skill) are always a problem in these competitions. So what is the sport actually about? And is it relevant to that end? Is it about peak performances and world records? Is it about a fair competition between competitors? Is it meant to be motivating for the average person to pursue those goals? Or is all of that irrelevant and it's just entertainment? Is it about winning? Is it about making money (so maybe it's just a spotlight and the winner is the one with more high paying advertisement deals?)? Is it about personal improvement?

And depending how you answer these questions you get different results on what is "fair" or "unfair".

Also depending on his motives he might have pulled the straw man fallacy upon you that is he attacked a false comparison which is easy to defend for him as "rule breaking in chess" ≠ "sexual harassment", but he ignored the actual argument that rule breaking isn't good just because it gives you points. So it's again one of those rhetoric slight of hands where you score pyrrhic victories to convince an audience of a better argumentation when in reality, this did nothing to debunk your argument that "not everything is ok as long as it scores you points", it just side tracked the argumentation by attacking a much weaker argument.

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate your answer

Answer (score 1):

The fallacy you are being accused of is "**false analogy**." (https://www.txst.edu/philosophy/resources/fallacy-definitions/faulty-analogy.html) Like all fallacies, it has force because it is similar to a good method of argument, in this case, "valid analogy." Analogies work by comparing two things. Something that is harder to understand, more abstract, more complex, or more controversial, is explained by relationship to something easier to understand, more concrete, simpler, ore more accepted. A valid analogy compares two things that are legitimately similar in relevant ways, a false analogy starts from a superficial similarity and derives an illegitimate or irrelevant conclusion.

In an informal argument like this one, it can be difficult to tell the difference. If we formalized your argument it would be something like: "We take as a given that sexually harassing someone to increase your ranking is wrong. Therefore doing something just for the purposes of increasing your ranking is wrong. Therefore refusing to resign in the hopes someone might get frustrated and resign is wrong." Your interlocutor is saying this is a false analogy because there is a significant difference--**sexual harassment is a serious offense, and we would consider it wrong in any context, not just chess**. Our intuition that it is wrong might therefore not have anything to do with the fact that it's being practiced for the purposes of increasing a ranking.

I think [he] is correct in this case. But a bad argument does not entail a wrong conclusion. **There are more legitimate arguments** against his behavior--he is winning for reasons that have little do do with his actual chess skills. An valid analogy would focus on this aspect of the situation, perhaps along the lines of "This would be like winning a swimming race solely because you put ice-cubes in the water. It isn't testing your swimming skills, just your endurance."

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I actually agree with everything you said, and I don't think my analogy refutes his argument. I feel that he can say something like "OK, I agree that increasing my rating by itself is not enough to justify my behavior, it is just 1 of the reasons why I do it ,here  are the others". I am trying to get him to talk about the other reason(s) why he feels never resigning is fine, so we can move the discussion forward, but I have trouble communicating that without exaggerated analogies and get trapped in an emotional argument because of that